# Different sort results between Oracle and Postgres with Special Characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

*Apologies as I know this question has been asked before, but tried the previously suggested approaches and none fixed my issue.

I am trying to compare a table found in two databases.

```
COLUMN_VALUE
01.00^01.13
01.00 01.12
01.00 01.15
```

Unfortunately, the table does not have a primary key, so I am trying to order by the same column and compare that way.

When I sort the above table in Oracle, it sorts to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '01.00 01.12' AS "COLUMN_VALUE" FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '01.00^01.13' AS "COLUMN_VALUE" FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '01.00 01.15' AS "COLUMN_VALUE" FROM DUAL) ORDER BY 1;

COLUMN_VALUE
01.00 01.12
01.00 01.15
01.00^01.13
```

However, when I perform the sort in Postgres, it sorts to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '01.00 01.12' AS "COLUMN_VALUE"
UNION ALL
SELECT '01.00^01.13' AS "COLUMN_VALUE" 
UNION ALL
SELECT '01.00 01.15' AS "COLUMN_VALUE") T1 ORDER BY 1;

COLUMN_VALUE
01.00 01.12
01.00^01.13
01.00 01.15
```

This issue appears to be how the `^` character is sorted. Does anyone know a workaround so that both databases sort the information the same way?

Comment: since there is not PK, comparing the values via computed SHA2 (or higher) digests, may be better option. As long as counts match and the SHA2 of the values match - that should provide proof of equality.

Comment: No - if you run that exact code in PostgreSQL, you don't get the result you posted. You get the same result as in Oracle. (I just tested it on DB Fiddle.) As for your true question: you said the data resides in a table, it is not created on the fly as in your example. If so, what is the **data type** of the column (in the Postgre table) that holds these values?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what other solutions you've tried, so that people don't have to waste time suggesting them to you again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating hash values and using them for ordering seems to be an option.

Test tables (Postgresql / Oracle)

[image] [image]

Query (Postgresql) - order by MD5 hash

```
select c_, md5( c_ )
from test
order by 2 ;

-- result
c_              md5
01.00 01.12     335dca42dedecedc19ba65065a7777ec
01.00^01.13     4e1661df191eb006274be5552a998280
01.00 01.15     c1197d14549263a867fd9850f42b68b1
```

Query (Oracle) - order by MD5 hash

```
select c_, standard_hash( c_ , 'MD5' )
from test
order by 2 ;

C_              STANDARD_HASH(C_,'MD5')
01.00 01.12     0x335DCA42DEDECEDC19BA65065A7777EC
01.00^01.13     0x4E1661DF191EB006274BE5552A998280
01.00 01.15     0xC1197D14549263A867FD9850F42B68B1
```

If the MD5 is not good enough, you can also use SHA256, which will probably give you a different ordering, but the same order result for both Postgresql and Oracle.  Examples on DBfiddle, for [Postgresql 12](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4ecbc5af594eab2b4c80cbc4fc8d9fd8) and [Oracle 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb741936b6ce831d939157f856a6d68a).

Answer (score 1):

Postgres:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '01.00 01.12' AS "COLUMN_VALUE" 
UNION ALL
SELECT '01.00^01.13' AS "COLUMN_VALUE" 
UNION ALL
SELECT '01.00 01.15' AS "COLUMN_VALUE") T1 ORDER BY "COLUMN_VALUE" COLLATE "C";

 COLUMN_VALUE
--------------
 01.00 01.12
 01.00 01.15
 01.00^01.13
(3 rows)
```

> I know this question has been asked before, but tried the previously suggested approaches and none fixed my issue.

Well, the answer is in [Different behaviour in "order by" clause: Oracle vs. PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528216/1995738)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but for some reason I was still getting different sort results in my actual use case so not sure what is going on.